# Spring Mongodb query for Employee first and last name and dob using range criteria

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have some data on employees which stores typical information like first and last name and dob, etc...  The business case I have been given requires me to pull a record for an employee based on a criteria of first name, last name and dob.

At first I thought this would be easy, but after doing a search in db, I found the dob records have differing timestamps (which doesn't make sense).  Without getting into the internal company issues of addressing this,  I need my query to look at a dob with a start of day and end of day range.

My sample code below demonstrates my latest effort to solve this issue but have not been able to match results with what i see in the db.  This code is using Spring Mongodb Query and mongoDbTemplate for constructing the queries.  I could really use some help in figuring this one out.

I have to set a date range to ensure I get the employee for that day but can't figure out how to construct the query correctly.

sample method:

```
    @Slf4j
    @Repository
    public class EmployeeDao {

        private static final int START_OF_DAY = 0;
        private static final int END_OF_DAY = 1;

        @Getter private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate; 

        @Autowired 
        public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {

            DB db = mongoTemplate.getDb();
            mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(db.getMongo(), "EmployeeDB");
            this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
        }

        public List<Employee> findEmployeeByNameIdDobRange(String lName, String fName, Date dob){

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            String startFmt = df.format(convertTo(dob, START_OF_DAY));
            String endFmt = df.format(convertTo(dob, END_OF_DAY));

            Query q = new Query();
            q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("employee.firstName").regex(fName, "i")
                    .and("employee.lastName").regex(lName, "i")  
                    .andOperator(
               Criteria.where("employee.dob").gte(startFmt).lte(endFmt) 
                )
            );

            return return getMongoTemplate().find(q, Employee.class);
        }

        private Date convertTo(Date dt, int startOrEnd){

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dt);

            switch (startOrEnd) {
                case END_OF_DAY:
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
                    break;
                case START_OF_DAY:
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("starOrEnd paramter does not equal 0 for beggining or 1 for end of day");
            }
            log.info(cal.toString());
            return cal.getTime();
        }
```

I appreciate any suggestions that can be made.  Thanks!

Comment: Add your employee document class

Comment: What is your java version ? Are your dates saved as string in db ? Can you share a sample document from your collection ?